# Remove autop from wordpress html widgets

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting unwanted

tags in my html code when I put it in an html widget block. I tried below methods but none of the seem to be working.

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('widget_text_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('widget_custom_html_content', 'wpautop');
```

I entered this html code in the html widget box

```
<img href="test.jpg">
<span>text</span>
<script>alert("message");</script>
```

And I get the below code after the widgets are saved. (There are some "p" & "br" tags which isn't needed.)

```
<p><img href="test.jpg"><br>
<span>text</span><br>
<script>alert("message");</script></p>
```

(Please click and see the screenshot attached) [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w95j4.png)

Please help?
Thanks!

Comment: What is "unwanted"? What do you mean by "autop"?

Comment: @NicoHaase https://i.stack.imgur.com/w95j4.png

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, if possible, please avoid using screenshots

Answer (score 1):

`autop`s are auto generated html `<p>` tags around the wordpress content. If the "remove_filter" solution didn't work for you, then you could try something like this:

```php
add_filter('widget_text_content', 'your_theme_removing_autop', 999);
add_filter('widget_custom_html_content', 'your_theme_removing_autop', 999);

function your_theme_removing_autop($content)
{
  $content = str_replace(['<p>', '</p>'], ['', ''], $content);
  return $content;
}
```

Tested and works on my end. Let me know if you could get it to work too!

Comment: Sure it would! But in this case there is only one `p` tag which is auto generated by wordpress.

Comment: What if there are multiple? How does this also remove the unwanted `<br>` (and possible keep others)?

Comment: There are other workarounds for that scenario! Wordpress has other special functions to deal with those situations. For example, you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69029831/15040627) where i used "whitelisting" technique!