# Wordpress how to use line breaks while escaping html tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, line-breaks, email-confirmation

I would like to separate the `Welcome to %s` and `Thanks for creating account on %1$s` by making each appear in a separate row.

They are currently jammed together/messed up when translating the phrases on a `RTL` site.

```php
protected function send_account_email( $user_data, $user_id ) {
            
  $to      = $user_data['user_email'];
  $subject = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Welcome to %s', 'my-plugin' ), get_option( 'blogname' ) );
  $body    = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Thanks for creating account on %1$s. Your username is: %2$s ',
    'my-plugin' ), get_option( 'blogname' ), $user_data['user_login'] );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a "line break" to separate them out! You could use `html` tags such as:

- `br` tag
- `p` tag
- `h1` tag

Just to name a few!

BUT you're using `esc_html__` to  translate AND escape `html`. Why do you need to use `esc_html__` to retrieve the name of your blog from your database? Why?

That being said, there is a whitelisting technique you could use to `translate` and `escape unwanted html` at the same time.

Using `wp_kses` you would be able to define a "white-list" for allowed `html` tags and escape the rest of them.

You could read more about it:

> [`wp_kses`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/)

and

> [This post on whitelisting html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69029831/15040627)

---

So your code would be something like this:

Using `<br>` tag:

```php
protected function send_account_email( $user_data, $user_id ) {

  $whitelist_tags = array(

    'br' => array(),
  
  );
        
  $to      = $user_data['user_email'];

  $subject = sprintf(wp_kses(__('Welcome to %s <br>', 'my-plugin'), $whitelist_tags), get_option( 'blogname' ));

  $body    = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Thanks for creating account on %1$s. Your username is: %2$s ',
      'my-plugin' ), get_option( 'blogname' ), $user_data['user_login'] );
}
```

---

OR using `<p>` tag:

```php
protected function send_account_email( $user_data, $user_id ) {

  $whitelist_tags = array(

    'p' => array()
  
  );
        
  $to      = $user_data['user_email'];
  
  $subject = sprintf(wp_kses(__('<p>Welcome to %s </p>', 'my-plugin'), $whitelist_tags), get_option( 'blogname' ));

  $body    = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Thanks for creating account on %1$s. Your username is: %2$s ',
      'my-plugin' ), get_option( 'blogname' ), $user_data['user_login'] );
}
```

---

OR using `<h1>` tag:

```php
protected function send_account_email( $user_data, $user_id ) {

  $whitelist_tags = array(

    'h1' => array(),
  
  );
        
  $to      = $user_data['user_email'];

  $subject = sprintf(wp_kses(__('<h1>Welcome to %s </h1>', 'my-plugin'), $whitelist_tags), get_option( 'blogname' ));

  $body    = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Thanks for creating account on %1$s. Your username is: %2$s ',
      'my-plugin' ), get_option( 'blogname' ), $user_data['user_login'] );
}
```

**Note:**

- `$whitelist_tags` is an array, so you could add multiple tags to it!
- Also, I've only used those tags in your `$subject` variable, you could use the exact technique in your `$body` variable too, if you need to!
- I've also used `__()` with combination of `wp_kses` instead of `esc_html__` in order to `translate` AND `escape unwanted html`!